# Parse embedded Struct form values in GoLang

Tags: angularjs, forms, parsing, go, struct

I have a struct that includes an array of another struct, eg

```
type Struct1 struct {
  Value         string
  Items         []Struct2
}
type Struct2 struct {
  Value         string
}
```

I am using gorilla schema to decode my Form values into Struct 1.
The values for the embedded struct, Struct 2, are not coming through.

When I look at the logs for the FormValue("Struct2") it returns '[Object object], [Object object]'

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**EDIT**
An example of the structure of the form,

Using AngularJS,

```
var data = $scope.struct1;
$http({
      method: 'POST',
        url:url, 
        data : data, 
        headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        transformRequest: function(obj) {
        var str = [];
        for(var p in obj)
        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
        return str.join("&");
    }

    })
    .then(function successCallback(response) { 
        console.log(response);                       
    }, function errorCallback(response) {

    });
```

Comment: This is possible because of you are not passing the extensions in structure.
Eg:-   HostCode string `json:"host_code"` where host_code is the exact match in json or xml.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you don't have the right struct design for your HTML form.  You might want to post your input and/or your HTML form design.

`gorilla/schema`'s `decode` expects the values input to be passed as a variable of type `map[string][]string`, as you can see both from [the example in the documentation](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/schema) and from the test files in the package.  Here's a simple complete script that just wraps the example from the documentation and prints the result:

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/schema"
)

type Person struct {
    Name  string
    Phone string
}

func main() {
    values := map[string][]string{
        "Name":  {"John"},
        "Phone": {"999-999-999"},
    }
    person := new(Person)
    decoder := schema.NewDecoder()
    decoder.Decode(person, values)
    fmt.Printf("Person: %v\n", person)
}
```

That outputs `Person: &{John 999-999-999}`.

That is the correct form for a map literal of type `map[string][]string`, as you can demonstrate by performing a declaration followed by an assignment and running it without error:

```
var values map[string][]string
values = map[string][]string{
    "Name":  {"John"},
    "Phone": {"999-999-999"},
}
```

Now `map[string][]string` doesn't obviously support all the types that gorilla/schema supports, such as the type in your question: slices of structs.  But the HTML form is processed such that a translation makes sense: it keeps appending indices and field names with dot separators to create the desired structure.  So for the types you posted in your question, I wrote this script to decode values into the structs:

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/schema"
)

type Struct1 struct {
  Value         string
  Items         []Struct2
}

type Struct2 struct {
  Value         string
}

func main() {
    values := map[string][]string{
        "Value": {"the thing with the items"},
        "Items.0.Value": {"a"},
        "Items.1.Value": {"b"},
        "Items.2.Value": {"c"},
    }
    s1 := new(Struct1)
    decoder := schema.NewDecoder()
    decoder.Decode(s1, values)
    fmt.Printf("S1: %v\n", s1)
}
```

Running that outputs:

```
S1: &{the thing with the items [{a} {b} {c}]}
```

That demonstrates that decode can populate your struct design without error, if its input matches that design.

So you might try to verify that your input matches that scheme -- that it has those array-like indices and field names with the dot separator in a way that conforms to your struct design.  And if it does not, that indicates that your struct design needs to be updated to fit the format of your input.

You can see examples of decode working on this type of structure in [the decode_test.go file in the gorilla/schema package](https://github.com/gorilla/schema/blob/master/decoder_test.go), such as these lines:

```
type Foo struct {
    F01 int
    F02 Bar
    Bif []Baz
}

type Bar struct {
    F01 string
    F02 string
    F03 string
    F14 string
    S05 string
    Str string
}

type Baz struct {
    F99 []string
}

func TestSimpleExample(t *testing.T) {
    data := map[string][]string{
        "F01":       {"1"},
        "F02.F01":   {"S1"},
        "F02.F02":   {"S2"},
        "F02.F03":   {"S3"},
        "F02.F14":   {"S4"},
        "F02.S05":   {"S5"},
        "F02.Str":   {"Str"},
        "Bif.0.F99": {"A", "B", "C"},
}
```

The `Foo` struct has a field named `Bif` of type `[]Baz`.  `Baz` is a struct -- so we have a slice of structs type, like in your question.  `Baz` has a field named `F99`.  You can see that the input is referenced with the string value `"Bif.0.F99"`.

Use this and other examples in the test file as your guide.

Comment: I have added more info, including form structure above